# Delete ZFS filesystem with snapshots but no other children?

Tags: zfs

You can delete a ZFS filesystem (or other dataset) with `zfs destroy <dataset>`.  That fails if the dataset has children, including snapshots.  `zfs destroy -r <dataset>` will remove the filesystem and its children, but will also destroy any non-snapshot children of the filesystem.  Is there a succinct way to say "Delete this filesystem and its snapshots, but only if it has no non-snapshot children"?

Basically, I have a number of nested filesystems and I'm using snapshots extensively, both for replication and for cheap backups.  I would like a way to easily remove child filesystems and their snapshots (e.g. `zfs destroy tank/container/leaf`) while providing a modicum of protection against accidentally nuking the entire filesystem collection (e.g. `zfs destroy tank/container<enter>leaf`)

In case it matters, I'm using ZFS on Linux with Scientific Linux 7.

---

**Solution**:

Based on longneck's comment, I can do this with two lines:

```
zfs destroy tank/example/leaf@%
zfs destroy tank/example/leaf
```

I've tested it and it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I have seen in other posts that you can remove all snapshots like this:

```
zfs destroy -rv dataset_or_vol_name@%
```

You could then follow-up with your `destroy` command to remove the database.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a one liner, but you could use the output from

```
zfs list -t all -r -H <dataset>
```

And have a script go through it and verify things carefully and destroy the the appropriate filesystems.